# QGIS crashes by opening project

Tags: qgis, qgs

Suddenly I got a problem opening the project I was working on since a long time.
When I open the project, QGIS crashes.

I think the problem might be in one layer, but as I cannot open the project I neither can delete this layer in QGIS desktop. Is there any option to do this another way?

Comment: could be this issue: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the qgs file with any text editor, look for the layers, and delete that manually.
Better make a copy in advance before editing.

Or open a new project, and add your layer there, and look if it behaves strange.

Comment: So logic, but I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot Andre Joost!!!

Comment: It turns out this was not a good idea: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53332/i-am-unable-to-draw-a-shape-layer

Comment: It caused some other problems, but at least it allowed me to open something.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that QGIS tends to crash if the project file (.qgs) contains outdated file paths (after deleting/moving files on disk).

In particular this seems to be true for RELATIVE paths (i.e. something like './xy/z.asc'.)

I was able to fix it by correcting the bad relative paths in the .qgs file manually (in text editor).