# I am unable to draw a shape layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, digitizing

When I add a new shape layer or want to edit an existing one, nothing is happening. I even don't see the dots where I'm clicking.

Maybe the problem is I deleted some layers (by opening the .qgs as a txt-file) as my project was collapsing by opening. I deleted three layers (maplayer and legendlayer, from start to end). Could there be some problem. The file is at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/83565282/AA_SR_Mendae.qgs

When I open a new project everything is fine.

Thanks a lot for all your help!!

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa

Comment: Seems like you deleted some vital information from your project file. Do you have a backup? Can you show what you deleted?

Comment: First I deleted the part called legendlayer
    <maplayer minimumScale="0" maximumScale="1e+08" geometry="Polygon" .... until the next </maplayer>

As this seemed not enough to make the project open again I also deleted the part of maplayer for the same layer
<maplayer minimumScale="0" maximumScale="1e+08" ... until the next  </maplayer>

Comment: Can I ask why you are hacking the project file?

Comment: Because I could not open the project anymore. Each time I opened it, it crached at 40 %. As I had just before added two new layers I could only think about taking out those two layers. And that seemed a solution to be able to open the project againt.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52730/qgis-crashes-by-opening-project

Comment: Could you please upload your current .qgs file somewhere so we can check what is missing?

Comment: Also, did you try launching QGIS from a terminal so that errors will be possibly shown?

Comment: Without looking at the damaged file, I guess you have to adjust the layercount="xy"> as well.

Comment: I uploaded the project file:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/83565282/AA_SR_Mendae.qgs
Thanks for the tip. I adjusted the layercount, a good step forward, but not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file crashes here too in Lisboa, but not in QGIS Master. If you are on Windows, you can install QGIS Master via OSGoe4w-setup in parallel to Lisboa.

QGIS Master complains here about missing files, of course.

**EDIT**

After some testing, I identified your point layers as causing the crash. You don't have to delete them from legend, or reassign the number of maplayers. Not sure if all are affected, but it is not only the first one. Reason might be that they are text-delimitered. Maybe it would be better to save them to shapefile and work on that.

Comment: Thanks!!
There I have another problem, when installing Master or anything with OSGeo4W Installer, I get: "access denied"
And I'll transform txt to shp if that's better, but I suppose that's not the problem as I was using it the same way before. No?

Comment: Not sure about the access denied, maybe some kind of rights on C:\. For the text files, <labelfield>Resistivity (?.m), a=30m </labelfield> seems a bit strange. Try a field name without (?, as these may spoil at some point. You could test it on a separate new project.

Answer (score 0):

I continued trying and removed the properties of the .qgs (opened as txt-file): digitizing , north arrow, scale bar and those things. Afterwards everything works fine, there must have been an error in one of those things!?

PD: Hoping I didn't create some new problems by hacking the file. Anyway, I can continue working now!

Comment: On my side, that does not help. QGIS crashes before the properties, unless I delete all point layers.